# Are passwords sent via a bash script retrievable?

Tags: security, bash, logging, shell, password

As part of running a backup script for a linux server, I have commands like mysqldump within a bash script which contain the mysql root password, and certain ftp server passwords. Are these retrievable by a malicious user, from the server logs?

I know that while the script is being run, processes like mysqldump can be viewed with the command line parameters, on invoking a `ps ax`. Do these get logged to server logs? If so, how can I cleanup after script execution? Is it at all possible to avoid these issues altogether?

Addendum:
My question is not specifically regarding mysqldump. There are other binaries like lftp and mysqldump that require passwords as an argument. I am aware that mysqldump accepts file inputs, as does lftp. However, is it possible to generically protect commands invoked in a bash script, which may contain sensitive information, from snooping?

Comment: intresting scenario , +1

Comment: This isn't an "exact" duplicate, but the Accepted Answer has the solution you're looking for.

Comment: I wasnt looking for a mysqldump specific solution. I am wondering how to secure passwords sent via bash scripts, from snooping.

Answer (score 0):

The history command will bring up a list of commands you have typed. In theory this data could be retrievable.

Answer (score 0):

There is no generic solution for this. Tools must provide their own protection for sensitive data such as passwords. Usually, they can load credentials from a file which must be protected appropriately, like mysql with `--defaults-file=`. Command line arguments cannot be protected.